# Angular attribute directive value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get a value straight from an attribute directive:

```
 <form cronos-dataset="People as p">
     Form Content
 </form>
```

In my JS I tried:

```
app.directive('cronosDataset',[function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'CronosGenericDatasetController',
    scope: {
        "cronos-dataset" : '@'
    }
  };
}])

.controller("CronosGenericDatasetController",['$scope', function($scope) {
    alert($scope["cronos-dataset"]);
}]);
```

I want to alert `"People as p"` string but I get `undefined`. Is that right path or should I go thorough a different approach?

Comment: you need to use `$timeout(function(){alert($scope["cronos-dataset"]);})` inside controller

Comment: Can you crate a plnkr/fiddle? Your code should work fine. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/2gdUSFoWXUTJAONqGLqn?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are supposed to have camelCase in the scope declaration

```
app.directive('cronosDataset',[function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'CronosGenericDatasetController',
    scope: {
        cronosDataset : '@'
    }
  };
}])
```

Here is a demo to see different variations
http://plnkr.co/edit/G6BiGgs4pzNqLW2sSMt7?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

Make a link function instead:

```
app.directive('cronosDataset',[function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        alert(attrs.cronosDataset);
    }
```

Comment: he does wanted to call inside controller not in link function?

Comment: That alerts! Thanks but I need to call it inside a controller!